# How to apply the AngularJS controller to the included page using ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two html pages, main.html and nested.html, so the nested.html is actually included in main.html, this way:

main.html starts

```
<div ng-include src="'nested.html'"></div>
```

main.html ends

**FULL CODE**

nested.html

```
<html>
<h1> I am included, but controller not sending the values to me. </h1>

<input type="text" id="myDatePicker"/>

</html>
```

main.html

```
<html ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1> I am main.html and controller working properly on me, please take care of my child **given below** </h1>

    <div ng-include src="'nested.html'"></div>
</html>
```

Controller Code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('bootstrapApp').controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);


function MainCtrl($scope, $location, $http, $compile) {

    $("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
        orientation: 'left'
    });


}

});
```

The Controller code makes the text field a datepicker using jquery. The input field is in nested.html page. If the controller works on the included page, the textfield becomes a datepicker. **That's it**

> Please guide me through how do I apply the same controller **MainCtrl** to included nested.html page

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the controller code and the code you are trying to render in `ng-include`

Comment: @ShashankVivek I edited the question, please see it.

Comment: I get a feeling that you are doing things in wrong way. 1. Dont use jquery datepicker with AngularJS. Use datepicker which are for AngularJS. You can get it over google. 2. Once that;s done try your code, as for now, your code seems incomplete over SO . Try creating a plunkr with that datapicker and update the question with the url. It'll immediately look into it. As of now, I can keep on guessing which will waste our time. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 important things to mention here:

1. The controller scope of the **MainCtrl** is already applied to the included nested.html. You can review that in the following Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/cvILaL3VvnJ5c1YDHDT1/.
2. You shouldn't use a jQuery datepicker from out of a AngularJS controller. Instead use a datepicker, which is intended for AngularJS (e.g. [angular-datepicker](https://720kb.github.io/angular-datepicker/))

Comment: I noticed now. It's working, Thanks. But why datepicker is not working. if I do like <ng-controller="MainCtrl"/> in nested.html the datepicker works otherwise not.

Comment: This is because of different runtime behaviors of jQuery and AngularJS. The jQuery code runs before Angular evaluates the ng-include and includes you child view.

Answer (score 1):

from what I can guess,you must be using `$scope.someVar` and you are trying to render it in `ng-include`. Try creating an obj inside the `controller` like below:

```
$scope.obj= { 
   someVar : 'Value'
};
```

and use it in `ng-include` i.e. **nested.html** as  `{{obj.someVar}}`.

#### Update 1

As per your new update, try AngularJS datepicker and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add controller into nested.html file like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <h1> I am included, but controller not sending the values to me. </h1>
  <input type="text" id="myDatePicker"/>
</div>
```

And from your comment:

Comment: if we do it like this, the new scope will be created for nested.html file, that will result in loss of data from the controller that's initiated on main.html like this.

Comment: Use ng-init, to pass data.

Comment: Or better, think how to structure data with router, and don't use ng-include, use named views.

Comment: @ CarnaruValentin Thanks, datepickers worked after I used ng-init. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "You should mark one of the answers as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to that answer."